# Only part of the PHP form variables are getting inserted into the MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

### The Situation::

I am using PHP to connect to a MySQL database and insert some demographic type form generated variables and some scoring results generated calculated variables.
**The demographic "form" generated variables are being** **properly inserted** *** ... but the scoring results generated calculated variables are not***. However in the email that automatically gets sent to the user upon the form's submission, those scoring results generated calculated variables are sent and are correctly calculated, plus in the echoed/printed splash screen, both types of variables are visible.
The form by the way is a job satisfaction survey with 15 questions each question with 7 options (radio button) and each option is worth a different number of points.
I have worked on this for 5 days, read all threads related to this topic on this web site, tried many different configurations but with no success and cannot find a way to insert those last 7 variables values (skill_variety, task_identity, task_significant, autonomy, feed_back, total, MPS) into the MYSQL database.

I am using hidden input to insert the scoring results calculated variables, but have not succeeded

```
<FORM  METHOD=POST action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" NAME="action" id="action"  onSubmit="return validate(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="skill_variety" id="skill_variety" value="<?php echo $_POST['skill_variety'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task_variety" id="task_variety" value="<?php echo $_POST['task_variety'] ?>" />
```

If more code is needed I will be glad to add it. Just let me know.

I know you folks are helpful and also many times frustrated by questions   like this but I hope you can offer a professional reach out and some   suggestions. I already have thin hair and hope not to pull the rest of it   out before its scheduled time.

### **My Need**

Some direction /suggestion/solution  for getting those recalcitrant variables (skill_variety, task_identity, task_significant, autonomy, feed_back, total, MPS) inserted into the targeted MYSQL table.

With thanks in advance for any direction and hope I have been clear and complete in this post.

BTW here is testing URL if it would help to see the situation "en vivo"   http://www.marscafe.com/php/hr2/master_9.php

**Here is the database set up**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb3 (  
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    s varchar(60),  
    name varchar(50),  
    email varchar(50),  
    ordered varchar(4),  
    optype varchar(50),  
    rate varchar(50),  
    time timestamp not null default now(),  
    skill_variety varchar(8),  
    task_identity varchar(8),  
    task_significant varchar(8),  
    autonomy varchar(8),  
    feed_back varchar(8),  
    total varchar(8),  
    MPS varchar(12),  
    PRIMARY KEY (id)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

**Here are the INSERT & CONNECT PHP CODES**

```
<?php

//MySQL Database Connect
include '../../../../phpinc.php';

// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

// Connect to MySQL variables are defined in the include file
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbName );

// Check the connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
}

// Insert the  data
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mydb3` ( name, email, ordered, optype, rate, skill_variety, task_identity, task_significant, autonomy, feed_back, total, MPS )
            VALUES 
            ( 
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ordered'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['optype'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['rate'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['skill_variety'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['task_identity'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['task_significant'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['autonomy'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['feed_back'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['total'])}',
                '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Motivating_Potential_Score'])}'
            )";

$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

echo $sql;

// Print response from MySQL

if ( $insert ) {
print("<br>");
echo  "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
} else {
die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}
##  #$mysqli->close();    has been moved from here  to after the automated email code
?>
```

**Here is what happens as printed on the splash screen using echo $sql;**

```
INSERT INTO mydb3 (name, email, ordered, optype, rate, skill_variety,   task_identity, task_significant, autonomy, feed_back, total, MPS) VALUES (   'Jack White', 'mars@marscafe.com','NO', 'Other','Other', '','', '','',    '','','' )  
Success! Row ID: 46  
skill_variety -- 15  
task_identity -- 18  
task_significant -- 6  
autonomy -- 9  
feed_back -- 4  
total -- 52  
MPS -- 468
```

**Here is what happens as printed on the splash screen using**

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";   

Array (  
    [action] => true  
    [skill_variety] =>   
    [task_variety] =>   
    [name] => Jack White  
    [email] => mars@marscafe.com  
    [rate] => Other  
    [ordered] => NO  
    [optype] => Other  
    [question-1-answers] => E  
    [question-2-answers] => F  
    [question-3-answers] => B  
    [question-4-answers] => C  
    [question-5-answers] => A  
    [question-6-answers] => G  
    [question-7-answers] => G  
    [question-8-answers] => G  
    [question-9-answers] => G  
    [question-10-answers] => D  
    [question-11-answers] => D  
    [question-12-answers] => D  
    [question-13-answers] => D  
    [question-14-answers] => D  
    [question-15-answers] => D  
)
```

Comment: You may want to learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Your using $_POST['Motivating_Potential_Score'] in your sql. I don't see that in the html page.

Comment: Don't use data from _GET  / _POST directly in your sql... unless you want your data wiped.  http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 2):

I looked into your Code and you might just try to insert things which are not there.

First of all, this is what is sent from your user to the Server:

```
action:true
skill_variety:
task_variety:
name:TestNibbels
email:TestNibbels@dow*****ht.de
rate:Chef
ordered:YES
optype:Corporation
question-1-answers:C
question-2-answers:C
question-3-answers:D
question-4-answers:E
question-5-answers:C
question-6-answers:C
question-7-answers:C
question-8-answers:C
question-9-answers:C
question-10-answers:C
question-12-answers:C
question-13-answers:C
question-14-answers:C
question-15-answers:C
```

You see this list when you press F12 for the Debug-Console in Crome

[image]

or when you print $_POST like you did.
Jason K commented the missing $_POST[`Motivating_Potential_Score`]. And there is no `task_significant`, `autonomy`, `feed_back` and `total` sent back. Thatwhy your $_POST-Array is not set for these keys.

The following two lines are the reason why $_POST[`skill_variety`] and $_POST[`task_variety`] are empty but set. You see that in Line 8 and 9 of your last Codeblock.

```
<input type="hidden" name="skill_variety" id="skill_variety" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="task_variety" id="task_variety" value="" />
```

You try to relay these two variables back through your html-code. Why?
Try

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['skill_variety'] = 'something';
```

to store your values within your server while your visitor is answering your Form. 
When he has successfully submitted your code get this value back from your serverside stored session like this:

```
session_start();
$thisissomething = $_SESSION['skill_variety'];
```

Then you can omit these:

```
<input type="hidden" name="skill_variety" id="skill_variety" value="<?php echo $_POST['skill_variety'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="task_variety" id="task_variety" value="<?php echo $_POST['task_variety'] ?>" />
```

Secondly:
It seems like you forgot to process your `question-XX-answers` with some function.
Whatever this function is, it should probably fill up your values for your database. I mean those you (whyever) try to find in your POST-Request: 
`$_POST['skill_variety']` `$_POST['task_identity']` `$_POST['task_significant']` `$_POST['autonomy']` `$_POST['feed_back']` `$_POST['total']` `$_POST['Motivating_Potential_Score']`

Comment: You might have missed that the Array $_POST contains every variable that is sent from the user to your server. But nothing more. Except you fill it up by your own code. Those variables inside of the array $_POST are all the <input`s> with a name.

Comment: When you first load your site there cannot be anything inside $_POST except you put it there manualy !! thatwhy skill_variety/task_variety is there but empty.

Comment: Nibbles so something like this     <?php
    session_start(); // start up the PHP session!   
    $_SESSION['skill_variety'] = 'svscore';  
    $svscore = $_SESSION['skill_variety'];  
    ?>  and then change INSERT to '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['svscore'])}'

Comment: A general thing: This $_SESSION array is the same name-style like the $_POST array you already learned. But the $_SESSION-Array is a tool to remember things for  one unique user until he closes down his browser. To identify your guest, you have to call session_start(); once before you write or later read your stored values. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). About your specific question in your comment: $svscore is not $_POST['svscore']! Try real_escape_string($_SESSION['svscore']) or real_escape_string($svscore) if your values are stored there.

Comment: You have your PHP-Script saved as `master_9.php` and you send your values to  `master_9.php`. Thatwhy you somehow should know if the guest is `new` or just sent your formdata. This seems to be mixed up in your script. For a start, you maybe want to create a master_savevalues.php and send the user to this new php-script by changing `action="/php/hr2/master_9.php"` to `action="/php/hr2/master_savevalues.php"`. You can then have all the stuff you wanna ask in master_9.php and you process the received info and inform your guest in master_savevalues.php

Comment: Another Structure could help you aswell: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/uEAfRF8.png).

Comment: I have tried everything suggested and more but nothing works. What is depressing is that previous to the PHP upgrade (5.5 +++) it all worked. Granted the upgrade was made to improve security, but it also created a baffling new approach that is not user friendly. I thank all who pitched in trying to help......Chef Mars

Comment: Gentlemen,
After experimenting with session variables and seeing what was getting written to/inserted into the MYSQL database, I decided to restructure the PHP page and put the connection and insertion PHP code after the "arithmetic" code section of the page instead of before it. That with some fine tuning of the '$mysqli->real_escape_strings' for each variable, got it to fully work (without needing to implement any SESSIONS). Thanks again for the support, as the I Ching says perseverance furthers. You can try it out at the same URL that is in my original post.